# Closed Point Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, matrices

User enters a nxn Matrix (with each position set either to 0 or to 1).

An 0 value at a position impiles absence of the point and a 1 value implies presence of the point.

Now the user enters a value (m,k) and the program is required to find if the point (of mth column and kth row) lies in the area enclosed by the points.

Is there any algorithm to do it?

["Enclosed" means if some arbitrary closed shape can be drawn around the point of consideration by joining the already present (1 set points).
Two points can only be joined if they are vertically, horizontally or diagonally neighborhood points.]
[[image: A typical 3x3 Matrix]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhaCv.jpg)

Comment: If point (m,k) is point itself, should it return `true` ?

Comment: No it will not , until it is enclosed

Comment: What does "enclosed" mean? Please define it more formally.

Comment: "Enclosed" means if some arbitrary closed shape can be drawn around the point of consideration by joining the already present (1 set points). Two points can only be joined if they are vertically, horizontally or diagonally neighborhood points.

Comment: Usually [Flood-Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is used for this kind of purpose. Just run the algorithm until a point at the border of the grid was filled. If the algorithm terminates beforehand, your point is enclosed, otherwise it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is **not** enclosed if and only if a non-diagonal path of 0's exists touching a border.

For a given point just recursively check all it's vertical or horizontal neighbors (proceed if current neighbor is 0, skip otherwise, stop if on a border).

In case the matrix is/can be huge and the condition will be checked for many points, it'd useful to preprocess the matrix (like SergeyS said in his answer).

The approach could be sort of inverse of above algorithm.
Start at a border, mark a point touching it as open, recursively proceed spreading the open-property via touching 0's. A 1 can become open but can't spread the property.

Comment: That solves it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check all 4 neighboring places. As you describe it, I don't see a need for any complicated algorithm.

Here is some basic code in java assuming that the boolean array contains True where is 1 and False where is 0.

```
public boolean isEnclosed(boolean[][] arr, int m, int k) {
    if (m+1 >= arr.length || !arr[m+1][k])
        return false;
    }

    if (m-1 < 0 || !arr[m-1][k])
        return false;
    }

    if (k+1 >= arr[0].length || !arr[m][k+1])
        return false;
    }

    if (k-1 < 0 || !arr[m][k-1])
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: (Hope after the edit, its clear why your code won't work)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using BFS ([Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)). During each query you start to fill area around it till you face points or border of the board. If you hit border it means point is not enclosed by points.
One significant improvement over this is to pre-process whole grid initially and not to run BFS each query. After that you can answer queries in O(1) time.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit